# How to organize Behat features folder and context classes to share same steps?

Tags: php, testing, behat

I have 2 features, one context class for each feature.
The 2 features have common steps. I have created a Trait to put into the common steps.
But Behat says the steps are already defined...

I could repeat the common steps into each context with different names, but I don't want to repeat code.

[image]

behat.yml :

```
default:
  suites:
    web:
      contexts:
        - RegisterVehcileContext
        - ParkVehicleContext
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and the error message you are facing

Comment: Also, why not use a **single** context class for both?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `VehicleInMyFleetContext` that contains the steps `VehicleInMyFleetTrait` does.  Features can use steps from any Context in their context.

Maybe think ahead more as "Vehicle In My Fleet"  already sounds like a step, maybe  `FleetContext`.

Add this new context to your `contexts`:

```
default:
  suites:
    web:
      contexts:
        - RegisterVehcileContext
        - ParkVehicleContext
        - FleetContext
```

I prefer to share contexts so that any step in features or [via code](https://docs.behat.org/en/latest/cookbooks/accessing_contexts_from_each_other.html) can call any other step for reusue.

However, if you wanted the opposite where features only use their own dedicated context and not another... then you will need to create  and use multiple profiles:

```
RegisterVehcile:
  suites:
    web:
      contexts:
        - RegisterVehcileContext
ParkVehicle:
    web:
      contexts:
        - ParkVehicleContext
```

see [configuration of behat.yml](https://docs.behat.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration.html) for more information on profiles and [identifying your profile with command line tool](https://docs.behat.org/en/latest/user_guide/command_line_tool/identifying.html).

Different profiles are often used to implement the same feature but with different contexts, i.e. one uses a REST API directly whereas another uses the same REST API but via selenium  instead.